# The minimum of $\dfrac{x(1+y)+y(1+z)+z(1+x)}{\sqrt{xyz}}?$

Tags: optimization

> Can we use $AM\geq GM$ inequality to find the minimum of $\dfrac{x(1+y)+y(1+z)+z(1+x)}{\sqrt{xyz}}?$

I can find out that minimum is $6$, but can we use $AM\geq GM$ to show this?

Comment: Only if x,y,z are all positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand the expression 
$$x(1+y)+y(1+z)+z(1+x) = x+yz+y+xz+z+yx $$
From $\rm{AM} \geq \rm{GM}$ we get 
$ x+yz \geq 2 \sqrt{xyz}$, do the same for the other terms and add to conclude.

Comment: A small comment but the equality condition is from $x = yz$ and so forth which gives $x = y= z = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately: Using AM-GM for $6$ positive numbers: $ x + y + z + xy + yz + zx \geq 6\sqrt[6]{x\cdot y\cdot z\cdot xy\cdot yz\cdot zx} = 6\sqrt[6]{x^3\cdot y^3\cdot z^3} = 6\sqrt{xyz}$. So $\dfrac{x+y+z+xy+yz+zx}{\sqrt{xyz}} \geq 6$ with equality at $x = y = z = xy = yz = zx$ implying $x = y = z = 1$